# TabBatController with viewControllers

Tags: viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

In my tabBarController-based app, I have four tabs - tabA, tabB, tabC and tabD. The user will be able to jump between the tabs.

Now to my question:
 - tabA, tabB and tabD have single viewControllers
 - tabC though has 3 viewControllers - vc1, vc2 and vc3

I am running into issue where the app remembers which viewController the user was in last, and when the user taps tabC, the control goes to the last view controller that the user was in.  For example, let's say the following is the sequence:

1. User taps tabA : view controller for tabA is shown
2. User taps tabD : view controller for tabD is shown
3. User taps tabC : view controller vc1 is shown.  On tapping some action, the user is taken to vc3
4. User taps tabB : view controller for tabB is shown
5. User taps tabC : **the vc3 is shown - instead I'd like to show vc1**

So far, I have tried the following in vc1 of tabC, but the control does not come to vc1 at all:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

How can I tell tabC to always load vc1?

Regards - thanks in advance....
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to vc1 of tabC likely isn't getting called - `viewWillAppear:` only gets called when the view will appear on the display.

You might want to look at this function:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
   didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

([Link to Apple Developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate))

and this function:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

([Link to Apple Developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController))

If you implement this in your `tabBarController` delegate, you can act when the user selects tabC, ie:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
   didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController == \* tabC view controller */) {
        [tabCViewController.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.    I am not having luck w/ the suggestion.  I made the AppDelegate the TabBarControllerDelegate.  The callback function gets called - however, using the following code, I am not able to popToRootViewController - using         if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"vc1"]) {
      NSArray *tmp = [self.tabBarController.navigationController viewControllers];
           [self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];
        }   The tmp array shows zero viewControllers!

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller in tab3?  If so, right now your code is getting the `tabBarController`'s navagationController.  This isn't what you need - the tabBarController.navigationController would be above the tabBarController in the view hierarchy.  Try `[viewController.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];` instead of `[self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];`

Comment: Sorry to be pain - but i am still frustrated.  The popToRootViewController does not seem to do the trick for me.   One thing I'm wondering is:  tabC is the navigation controller.  It knows about the three VCs it is using (namely vc1, vc2, vc3).  How is the AppDelegate going to know about it - because it is the TabBarControllerDelegate?

Comment: Each of the view controllers vc1, vc2 and vc3 has a `navigationController` property.  For a given `UIViewController` instance, this property is set to the navigation controller that has this view in its stack.  So, AppDelegate gets the `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` call, and `viewController.navigationController` should have the navigation controller in tab3 (because viewController should be on that navigation controller's stack.)

Answer (score 0):

@dvorak:  Thanks for the answer - and sorry to drag on....

I know what I am writing is not an answer - but wanted to show the code that I am working with.

I am not having luck w/ the suggestion.  I made the AppDelegate the TabBarControllerDelegate.  The callback function gets called - however, using the following code, I am not able to popToRootViewController:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
       NSLog(@"ViewController is <%@>", viewController.tabBarItem.title);
       if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"tabC"]) {
           NSArray *tmp = [viewController.navigationController.tabBarController viewControllers];
          [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
       }
}
```

I collected the all ViewControllers in *tmp* variable , in a hope to see 3 ViewControllers in the array, after visiting all three VCs of tabC.  From tabC->vc3, I hit the tabB, and then hit tabC for my exercise.  The *tmp* array had zero elements in the debugger.